# expectation calculation problem small problem

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

a Continuous, positive random variable X, whose PDF is proportional to $(1+x)^{-4}$, where $0<x<\infty$, determine $E(X)$

i tried to solve it directly by integrating from 0 to infinity to get the CDF and use the non-negative formula but it doesn't yield the answer i need to, what happened?

Comment: Did you compute the proportionality constant for the PDF and CDF?  That is to say, the PDF is $f(x) = \alpha/(1+x)^4$, where $\alpha$ is some constant such that $\int_{x=0}^\infty f(x) \, dx = 1$.  Can you determine $\alpha$ from that?  Then the CDF $F(x) = \int_{t=0}^x f(x) \, dx$.

Comment: i found out the constant being 3, just one small question how do I determine whether I not i have to do the proportionality constant?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  The problem clearly states that the PDF is proportional (i.e., not necessarily equal) to $(1+x)^{-4}$, which implies there's a proportionality constant.  Obviously the integral of $(1+x)^{-4}$ from $x = 0$ to $\infty$ isn't $1$, so you must find out what the proportionality constant must be to ensure that the area under the curve does equal $1$.  Does that help?

Comment: ok i got it now thanks!!